# TV series: girl becomes a mermaid by rubbing a gel on her legs, brother grows into a man in one day

Tags: story-identification, tv, disney, mermaids

I remember watching a TV show where there's a family consisting of a father, mother, elder daughter and a son. The intro of the show is like any other intro just showing them and their names and some scenes from the show like some alien/robot shoots some green stuff at him and he jumps behind the couch. I watched it between 2002-2005.

I remember only two scenarios from the show:

1. Where the girl becomes a mermaid, she just applies some gel on her legs and it turns her into a mermaid and then she participates in a show.
2. Where her brother grows up into a man in a day and he has this robot, which looks exactly like him. In one scene, the robot goes to the fridge, has a drink and it all leaks from under his shoes (that's how it was shown).

I think it was from Disney, but I'm not sure.

In the intro the show name pops out with mostly green colour with some cartoon characters on top or something (vague).

It was a real show, not reality show. I think it might have the Micky Mouse and Goofy on its name logo. Not sure.

Comment: I'm tempted to say the Australian series *Round the Twist*; that definitely had a mermaid episode but I can't find a robot one.

Comment: Not that one I think. Any other ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the TV series *[Honey, I Shrunk the Kids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey%2C_I_Shrunk_the_Kids%3A_The_TV_Show)*; based on the movie of the same name. In this fun series, the family got into all sorts of trouble because of the dad's inventions. In one episode, "Honey, She's Like a Fish Out of Water", the daughter, Amy, is turned into a mermaid by a lotion invented by her father. From IMDb's summary:

> Wayne creates a skin lotion to make people become great swimmers like fish in the water. Amy takes some of it to a pool party that she is invited to. When Amy uses the lotion, she becomes the life of the pool party so the girl who the party is being held for tries it as well. However, things go terribly wrong (as usual) when the girls find the lotion has turned them into "mermaids". They'll end up completely turning into fish unless Wayne can create an antidote. However, things get even worse when the desperate and greedy owner of the pool kidnaps the girls to use them as a money-making attraction.

The robotic episode is "Honey, Growing Up Is Hard to Do":

> Nick wants to appear on a show called Smart Mouth because he believes he knows everything. Everyone tells him that he is too young so Nick makes a chemical which accelerates his aging process, turning him into a grown man overnight. But his parents eventually create an antidote so now they must convince Nick to go back to normal or he will be a grown up forever.

This episode introduces Animatronic Nick, which has a uncanny resemblence to Nick Szalinski. with the exception that only its face and hands look normal and the rest of his body is robotic.

[image: Honey, I Shrunk the Kids characters]
[image: Honey, I Shrunk the Kids logo]

Comment: Exactly. Thats the one.

Answer (score 2):

The description makes me think of the 1990 TV adaptation of *[Maniac Mansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maniac_Mansion_(TV_series))*.

> Maniac Mansion centers around the lives of the Edisons, an American family living in a large mansion in the upscale suburban neighborhood of Cedar Springs. The Edisons consist of patriarch Fred (Joe Flaherty), an eccentric scientist and inventor, his level-headed wife Casey (Deborah Theaker), and their children, teenage genius Tina (Kathleen Robertson), prepubescent Ike (Avi Phillips) and precocious toddler Turner (George Buza). Also living in the Edison mansion are Casey's brother Harry Orca (John Hemphill) and his wife Idella Muckle-Orca (Mary Charlotte-Wilcox).
>
> While Maniac Mansion primarily derives its storylines from typical sitcom fare such as family life and parent-child relationships, the series incorporated several prominent elements of science fiction. Fred Edison is a scientist who works out of his basement laboratory which is partially powered by a mysterious extraterrestrial meteorite, and many episodes revolve around Fred's outlandish and occasionally disastrous experiments and inventions. As it is revealed in the series premiere, a mishap with one of these inventions caused genetic mutations in two of the main characters, Turner Edison and Harry Orca, in a parody of the 1986 film The Fly: for the complete run of the series, toddler Turner is a fully-grown man with the mind of a child and Harry Orca is a normal-sized housefly with a human head (similar to the 1958 version of The Fly).

Comment: I dont think it is. The one I say is not that old I guess because the graphics and the clarity looks also like from the 2000s.

Comment: An the show name pops out with mostly green colour with some cartoon characters on top or something (vague).

Comment: @BLASTERS To be clear: The intro has cartoon characters, but was the show itself a cartoon, or live action?  Perhaps you should edit that into the question above.